# Auto Detect Mobile Device or Resolution and Adjust CSS accordingly

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to know how I would change the CSS settings of a menu bar according to the *device* or *resolution* of the screen (or one example of both device and resolution detection).

**For Example:**

A `black` menu bar has  `width:800px;` and  `height:50px;` normally, however, if the screen is bellow a certain resolution and/or a mobile device is detected, the `black` bar will change to a `blue` bar with  `width:300px;` and  `height:150px;`.

**I'm guessing this is simular to how it would work:**

If the `screen <= 300px, use this CSS` or if the `screen > 300px, use this CSS`.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Thanks for the info. An example based on the options I provided (width;/height;/background-color;) would be more beneficial for me and anyone else who wanted to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you would use Media Queries for. You can find MANY examples of how to use them throughout the web. Just Google "css media queries", but here is a really basic set of queries to give you an idea of how it works.

```
@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
  .menubar {
      // code for below 300px
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 301px) {
  .menubar {
     // code for above 301px
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
     #black-bar {
          width: 300px;
          height: 150px;
          background-color: blue;
     }

     /*Additional styles can be added like...
       body {background-color: green;}*/
}
```

You can also do @media print, if you want it to only perform this way when the page is printed, or just @media or @media all if you want it to perform in all cases.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries for detailed information.

Comment: No prob. I really stole the MDN link from @elclanrs.