# Changing the CSS of DIV 2 and 3 ONLY IF DIV 1 is below a certain resolution

Tags: javascript, css

Before you try and help me out, look at my previous question to get a basic idea of what I'm trying to accomplish [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885142/auto-detect-mobile-device-or-resolution-and-adjust-css-accordingly)

I want to adjust the positioning and sizes of two divs (logo and menu bar, *they are both a different shade of green*) that is located within the top div (black bar). The top div automatically adjusts its size according the the screen resolution.

[CLICK HERE TO SEE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk4mr/)

You can see how the `black bar` turns `blue` once its `under 320 pixels`. However, I want to adjust the positioning and sizes of the two green bars only when the black bar turns blue. How would I do this?

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is adding the positioning to the same media query as the color change out of the question?

Comment: I don't see how that would work. It would be great if you could show me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more styles to the media query declaration:

```
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
.menubar {
  /*/ code for below 320px /*/
  background-color:#00F;
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
    position:relative;
}

#top-nav-bar {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    top:auto;
}
#top-logo {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
}
```

View this demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/Rk4mr/7/**

Also to be sure your media query styles will work declare it at the bottom of the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple elements to the same media query.

```
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
    #top-nav-bar{float:right!important;width:80%!important;}
    #top-logo{float:right!important;width:20%!important;}    
    .menubar {
      /*/ code for below 320px /*/
      background-color:#00F;
      width:100%;
      height:150px;
  }
}
```

[See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Rk4mr/9/)

Also, if you use percentages instead of pixels you can ensure that elements wont cascade one row after another. (For example if the browser is 280 pixels wide, two elements that equal more than 280 wont fit on the same line)

Comment: If u can avoid the use of `!important`

Comment: What is the purpose of `!important` ?

Comment: When you add !important to a style, it will overwrite other styles that have priority over it.

Because you have widths assigned to it before, I used !important in this case to ensure that the media query takes priority over the other sizing styles.

Comment: @BertStarington The problem with `!important` is that it overrrides user's styles too. So maybe a client has vision problems and wants to change text color to read better, but he can't because of `!important`.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. So I'll only use it when its absolutely necessary. Thanks for the help guys.