# Website Changes Size on Browser but not on Mobile Device

Tags: css

Take a look at my previous question to have a basic understanding of what I'm doing [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885943/changing-the-css-of-div-2-and-3-only-if-div-1-is-below-a-certain-resolution).

I have created [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/kfgMf/) basic template with the help of *stackoverflow* members.

As you can see, when you re-size the window down to `480 pixels`, the website changes to fit the device, however, when i try this on my iphone, it still shows the original website. How can i fix this problem? Am I missing something?

[CLICK HERE FOR THE WEBSITE HTML/CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/kfgMf/)

Help will be appreciated.

**THE WEBSITE NOW WORKS THANKS TO THE ANSWER BELOW.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

in the `<head>` of the document.

Comment: Wow, it works. Thank you. Can you explain what each of the options mean? e.i. `veiwport` and `initial-scale=1` .